# Хром расширение. Установил ссылку на новую вкладку но фавикон не показывает

Tags: chrome-extension

Вместо тысячи слов (скриншот) :
[image: проблема]

В первом случае(слева) ссылка на страницу через расширение, во втором-прямая ссылка на ту же локальную страницу.

Смысл мини-расширения в том, чтобы поставить на новую открывающеюся вкладку свою кастомную страницу. Нажал новую вкладку- открылась вкладка с уже открытой страницей. Вот manifest.json:

```
{
 "manifest_version": 2,

 "name": "test",
 "version": "1.0",

 "chrome_url_overrides": {
  "newtab": "index.html"
 },

 "icons": {
   "16": "16x16.png"
 },

 "browser_action": {
  "default_icon": "16x16.png"
 }

}
```

и страница ссылающаяся на файл с именем index.html для примера

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>test</title>
    <link href="16x16.png" rel="SHORTCUT ICON"/>
</head>
<body>
teeeeeeeeeeeeeeest
</body>
</html>
```

Почему? Почему так происходит? И как это побороть?
Гуглил, но как-то тяжело сформулировать вопрос. Прошу понять и простить за такой вопрос, вероятно никому больше он не пригодится . Очень уж огорчает отсутствие фавикона.. (

Comment: нашел кое-что, но как это понимать? надежды нет? :Your problem is, that the `newtab` page doesn't have a favicon by default. You can try it with the `history` or `bookmarks` page because these two have one, but it won't work with `newtab`.

Comment: =(((((((((((( скажите что он не прав : Sadly it isn't possible to add a favicon to the `newtab` page. I hope you can live without it ;)

Comment: однако другие расширения делают это, определенно ,с помощью скриптов

Comment: Покажите пример приложения, которое перезаписывает newtab и вешает туда свою фавиконку.

Comment: @terron https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/replace-new-tab-page/cnkhddihkmmiiclaipbaaelfojkmlkja

Comment: Оно просто делает перенаправление на указанный в настройках сайт при открытии вкладки через `window.location`. Никакой магии.

Comment: Нет, у вас даже JavaScript'а нет, чтобы эта страница делала "то же самое". Вы показываете HTML-документ `index.html`, зашитый в расширение, и пытаетесь добавить ему фавиконку через элемент `<link>`, а то расширение, ссылку на который вы мне дали, сразу же перенаправляет пользователя на заданный в настройках сайт через `window.location`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавить фавиконку на страницу с новой вкладкой (`newtab`), к сожалению, нельзя. Ни через `<link>`, ни через манифест, ни через Chrome Extensions API.

Comment: Да, наверное в этом суть вопроса "можно ли обойтись без js" спасибо. Извините голосовать пока не могу.

Comment: @qwertet вы можете отметить мой ответ как решение галочкой слева, если он удовлетворил вас.